# how do I make a custom string attribute to all SKSpriteNodes?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, attributes

I want to make a second "name" attribute to every SpriteNode like this:

```
var MySprite = SKSpriteNode()
MySprite.name = "Sprite5"
MySprite.secondName = "FireGuy"
```

how do I accomplish this? I've tried using classes, however if i do like this:

```
class MySprite: SKSpriteNode{
var secondName = String()

}
```

then i cant do this:

```
for nodes in self.children{
     if node.secondName == "FireGuy"{
        print("yay!")
     }
}
```

Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'secondName'

Comment: You are using 2 different things "secondName" and "lastname". Should be using secondName instead.

Comment: I wrote it wrong in stackoverflow, sorry :/, It still doesnt work

Comment: Use the userData property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some like this with userData

```swift
extension SKSpriteNode {
    var secondName: String {
        set {
            if self.userData == nil {
                self.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
            }
            self.userData?["secondName"] = newValue
        }
        get {
            self.userData?["secondName"] as? String ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```swift
let node = SKSpriteNode()
node.secondName = "Name!"
print(node.secondName) // Print: Name!
```